# How do I test iOS upgrade scenarios?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I had basic and premium versions of my app installed on one of my test phones. I then updated the firmware to iOS 7.1 Beta 5.

The basic and premium versions have identical binaries (certain features are just switched on or off), but after upgrading, the premium version crashes on launch but not the basic version. I can run the pro version from xcode and see it's crashing because it can't find the model for the persistent store - cocoa error 134130 (though the check to whether  exists at the appropriate location returns true). I can run fresh installs of both versions of the app on the 7.1 simulator with no problems.

I'm not sure whether this is something related to the beta, or if I had a debug version of the premium app on the phone previously and that caused some problem after upgrading.

I'd like to be sure by doing some testing around installing it on 7.0, configuring it various ways, then upgrading to 7.1 and seeing there are any problems. But I'm not sure how to do this. If I run it on the simulator, then switch the simulator to 7.1, it doesn't preserve the apps. It won't let me restore back to a previous version for my test phone; I do have my personal phone running iOS 7 and I could test the upgrade on there, but without the ability to restore I could only run one test.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Download the iOS 7.0.6 IPSW. You can downgrade using Xcode, while iOS 7.1 is in beta.  (You'll lose all your data.)  I recommend buying an iPod Touch for this stuff, if your alternative is your personal phone.

Comment: Another thing I have seen developers do in this situation is put a note on the App Store (in the info for the new version) advising that if the app crashes after upgrading the system they should delete it and restore it afresh.

Answer (score 1):

Also possible copy you app from one simulator version to another `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/UUID-UUID-UUID-UUID-UUID` to another `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/UUID-UUID-UUID-UUID-UUID` and see what happens.

Simulator should be relaunched to reload available apps.

Comment: This idea is so amazing in its simplicity! I wasn't sure if it will work, so I tried, and it worked for me. In the similar way I can download all data files from device, using xcode organizer, and copy them to simulator folder to isolate issues on different version.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to find the crash is to view the crash logs in Organizer "Xcode -> window -> organizer"